# Canel upgrade from 3.16.0 to 3.19.0 HystrixConfigurationDefinition missing

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am updating Apache camel from 3.16.0 to Apache Camel 3.19.0 and getting below error.

Exception in thread **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected Exception parsing XML document from class path resource [myContext.xml]; nested exception us java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/camel/model/HystrixConfigurationDefinition;**

**Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.model.HystrixConfigurationDefinition at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)**

I tried finding the solution but No luck. I investigated dependency tree as well. I am new to Apache camel.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's resolved Now. I have added camel jaxb dependency

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be removed in 3.17 due to being deprecated

https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_17.html#_deprecated_components

```
The following components that had been marked as deprecated, were removed in this release:
    ... 
    
    • camel-hystrix
    
    ...
```

Comment: Yes I saw that but is there any work around?. We are not using it directly. May be this error coming from any one of the dependency: camel-core, came-spring, camel-jms, camel-jpa, camel-sql, camel-jetty, camel-quickfix

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to add camel-spring-xml (that helped me to fix)